# How to get all information from assembly?

Tags: c#, intellisense

I am creating intellisense as Java's intellisense at C#.I have TextBox which user can write what he wants to get.how to get all information from assembly as it is class,or const,or namespace,or primitive,or enum,or method ..? like in the picture

[image: like this]

Comment: are you creating an intellisense for java ?, i don't understand why you added the C# tag to the question

Comment: no i am creating it in C#,but intellisense is like Java's

Comment: Can you update your question to mention that, so that it will be easier to understand

Comment: Java doesn't have IntelliSense; Visual Studio does. Do you want to create IntelliSense like VS has for C#?

Comment: as mix of C# and Java intellisenses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really clear what you mean, but you should start with:

- [`Assembly.GetTypes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx)
- [`Type.GetMembers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmembers.aspx) or:

  - [`Type.GetFields`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getfields.aspx)
  - [`Type.GetMethods`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethods.aspx)
  - [`Type.GetProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperties.aspx) (etc)

If you *do* go for `Type.GetMembers`, you can distinguish between them using [`MemberInfo.MemberType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.membertype.aspx).

Basically look at all the members available on `Type`, `MethodInfo` etc... and if you have any more *specific* questions, we can probably be more helpful with those.

Comment: when i call assembly.GetTypes() method it returns all types whatever namespace ?

Comment: @JavidanGuliyev: Yes, it returns all the types in the assembly, regardless of the namespace. Use `Type.Namespace` to determine the namespace of a type.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you can use System.Reflection.Assemly class/methods to do that.

Comment: exactly from which ?i have assembly and i must recognize what is what.